# setState in React using input from imported component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have made a functional component called Age and have imported it into another functional component called Signup. I did this to dynamically render divs on one page depending on whether or not the user is authenticated and so I didn't have to pass down state from one component to another and instead just set the state of the user on a parent component.

Is there a way to set the userState on the Signup component with the input provided by the user on the Age component?

**Signup.js**

```
const Signup = () => {
  const [userState, setUserState] = useState({});
  const [authState, setAuthState] = useState(false);

  const renderDiv = () => {
    if(authState != false) {
      return <Age />
    } else { 
      return <SignUpMain />
  }
      
  }
  return <div> {renderDiv()} </div>
 

  
};

export default Signup;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

React allows you pass down any type of javascript objects to get in child component with `props`. In the example, you can pass a traditional object created from useState hook and use it in another component:

https://codesandbox.io/s/prod-bird-3y93l?file=/src/App.js:0-297

**parent**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

import Age from "./Age";

const Signup = () => {
  const [userState, setUserState] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(userState);
  }, [userState]);

  return <Age setUserState={setUserState} />;
};

export default Signup;
```

**child**

```
import React from "react";

const Age = ({ setUserState }) => {
  const changeUserState = () => {
    setUserState((state) => !state);
  };

  return <button onClick={changeUserState}>Toogle state</button>;
};

export default Age;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just pass down the function from signUp to Age component, then everything inputs inside Age component change, u just invoke the function passed from signUp

```js
const Age = (prop) => {

   return (
      <>
        ...
        <input oncChange={prop.onAgeInputChange} /> 
        ...
      </>
   )
}

const Signup = () => {
  const [userState, setUserState] = useState({});
  const [authState, setAuthState] = useState(false);

  const onAgeInputChange = (inputData) => {
     // update user state here
  }

  const renderDiv = () => {
    if(authState != false) {
      return <Age onAgeInputChange={onAgeInputChange} />
    } else { 
      return <SignUpMain />
  }
      
  }
  return <div> {renderDiv()} </div>
 

  
};

export default Signup;
```